# OSX 10.10, How to generate Core dump file after Sleep and panic?

Tags: macos, coredump, iokit

I knew how to two machine debugging.and now I meet a question.
my kext support System sleep. In my driver I realize setPowerState function.
but maybe something wrong happened druing setPowerState. 
when system falls to sleep, it crashed, never wake up. screen is black, press keyboard nothing happens,  I have to press the power button 5s to restart the system.
In common panic conditions, transmitting coredump file to coredump server is ok, but when system sleep->panic, no coredump file is transmitted! and two machine debugging is not work! kdp-remote can not connect to the client.
what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Firewire for kernel debugging/console logging? That shuts down later in the suspend process than ethernet. I can't guarantee that it will definitely catch your bug, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I am using Ethernet for debugging, Do they have different performance? I didn't notice that. Will try.

Comment: You can also output debug output via firewire (`fwkpfv` command on client machine, `kprintf()` function in your kext) which is extremely handy for this type of thing.